# How to detect client closing connection during piping stream over http in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, stream

I stream data from server to client in an expressjs (nodejs) application.

I do something like this;

```
// let contentType and filename be correctly defined in context

function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type',contentType);
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='+filename);
    require('fs').createReadStream('/path/file').pipe(res);
}
```

I would want to know when the client fails to download the file, but I don't get how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Listen for the `close` event on response object. This is emitted when the connection to the client is closed prematurely like refreshing the page or closing the tab.

```
require('fs').createReadStream('/path/file').pipe(res).on('close',function(){
   //do stuff for closed connection
})
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and before accept, but your response is usefull!